# Libgdx: disable spell corrector

Tags: libgdx

We are making an App on libgdx, and we have a page with the login. We need the user to insert their password without the spell corrector (so, we can avoid any tipe of error).

There is a way to disable spell corrector on the phone via libgdx?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you actually using for displaying text?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `isPasswordMode()` to `true` on the `textField` there will not be any spelling correction and characters will be hidden (the latter depending on the phone settings).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I cannot set isPasswordMode() because I have already a password field, which has to contain wildcard characters. :(

Is there another way?

Comment: You are not using textfields for this or?  Show what you have so far please.